# How do I call a C function in another module from inline assembler in IAR EWARM?

Tags: c, inline-assembly, extern, cortex-m, iar

I have a bit of assembly in a hard fault handler. The assembly is basically meant to pass the current stack pointer as a parameter (in R0). It looks like so...

```
__asm("    mov     r0, sp\n"
  "    bl      SavePC\n"
  "    bx      lr");
```

This works fine when SavePC is in the same c file. However, when SavePC is placed in another c file I have no luck. I have tried to IMPORT the function like so...

```
__asm("IMPORT SavePC\n"
" mov r0, sp\n"
" bl SavePC\n"
" bx lr");
```

... but I must be doing something incorrect. The compiler reports the following...

```
Error[Og005]: Unknown symbol in inline assembly: "IMPORT" 
Error[Og005]: Unknown symbol in inline assembly: "SavePC" 
Error[Og006]: Syntax error in inline assembly: "Error[54]: Expression can not be forward"
Error[Og005]: Unknown symbol in inline assembly: "SavePC" 
Error while running C/C++ Compiler
```

The c file with the assembly includes the header file with the SavePC prototype...

```
extern void SavePC(unsigned long);
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Do you have the function **SavePC** defined as extern in the file where this asm code resides?

Comment: @maths-help-seeker I include the header file for SavePC which has the prototype defined as extern - `extern void SavePC(unsigned long);`. Good?

Comment: Yup..I was going thru the manual of the assembler. It uses EXTERN <functionname>. Can you please check this as well instead of import?

Comment: @maths-help-seeker I tried that and the compiler comes back with... **Error[Og005]: Unknown symbol in inline assembly: "EXTERN" V:\interrupt_setup.c 137**

Comment: Ohh! then extern is not the right solution..

Comment: @maths-help-seeker Actually, I must be doing something wrong. I changed it back to IMPORT and it now says the same thing about IMPORT. I don't know how I could have overlooked that error before...

Comment: Infact, as per the manual, import and extern mean the same thing. :)

Comment: This page shows an example of how to write a good fault handler.  You don't need to use inline asm.  http://blog.frankvh.com/2011/12/07/cortex-m3-m4-hard-fault-handler/

Comment: @TJD: +1 good point. I hope you don't mind me copying that link into my answer at the [EE version of this question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/42917/how-do-i-call-a-c-function-in-another-module-from-inline-assembler-in-iar-ewarm).

Answer (score 3):

Your code won't work even with a correct call.

```
bl _SavePC
bx lr
```

What do you think will be the value in the `LR` register in the `bx lr` instruction?
The address of the instruction itself! The `bl` instruction has put it there.
This is effectively a `while (1);` with a bx instruction.

A nested function call looks more like this:

```
push lr
bl _SavePC
pop pc
```

To get the stack register one uses the corresponding CMSIS functions:

- `__get_MSP()` for the Main Stack Pointer (MSP)
- `__get_PSP()` for the Process Stack Pointer (PSP)

Answer (score 2):

Using extern is a bad habit since it is prone to errors. C-99 standard provides an safe alternative for extern. You should write the function prototype in the header file without extern keyword. Then include the header file in both C files. The linker is then responsible for linking the function in different files.

Example:

## File : custom_header.h

```
void SavePC(unsigned long);
```

## File : source_c_file.c

```
#include "custom_header.h"

void SavePC(unsigned long)
{
      ....
      ....

      ....

}
```

## File : user_c_file.c

```
#include "custom_header.h"

void someFunction(void)
{
.
.
.

__asm("    mov     r0, sp\n"
  "    bl      SavePC\n"
  "    bx      lr");

.
.
.
}
```